# How to disable running a program from command line

Tags: command-line, users

I have an installed program, say : "**firefox**", and I want (for some reason) to run it only if I double clicked the icon, 
and not form typing "**firefox**" in terminal.

is there any way to do that, for any program or executable file?

P.S: I want *any user* to open the program from icon, but only root or no one to open it from command line

Second P. S: I want that for some options in that program that can be used if I run it form terminal

**Edit:** Why?

Some program, have a **safe-mode** with all the adds-on disabled, ..this can happen from command line not from GUI,.. I want to disable the command line and only let the program accessible from icon, for all the users (except root).
this also the case of *firefox example*

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question is unusual, and will require quite a bit of haywiring...after which your system may not work properly. There are easier and more standard ways to restrict users.

Comment: So , u basicaly say my solution approach is the problem, .. there maybe other ways, and I am willing to give the details about it, but in general for **X** program ,this is the question, .. I know this could require "hacks", and that's okay for me ..

Comment: Probably not a good question for here, but rather for a general linux site. For a possible answer on your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux

Comment: What is the purpose of this? And do you need to absolutely prevent launching the application from the command line (probably impossible - but why would you even want that anyway?), or just prevent "accidental" launching from a terminal?

Comment: You can restart Firefox without add-ons from the Help menu though... or I believe even by holding down Shift while starting it.

Comment: @ByteCommander ,Not firefox, for *x* program where I can start a feature only form cmd , .. am arguing for all the firends whom might downvote this ..

Answer (score 1):

The basic theory answering your specific question:

- Use chown to ensure the application is owned by root:root.
- Use chmod to change the permission of the binary to 700, so nobody except root can access the application.
- Edit the .desktop file to ensure that root (instead of user, dbus, or any other user) is triggering the application upon click. Having root do this is generally unwise, and may have unexpected effects.

....and make sure your system is fully backed up, since this can be a really awful thing to do to your system. Much better to use a tool like `rbash` to prevent access to most applications by non-admin users.

Answer (score 1):

Something that you can do is to create a `.desktop` file. Basically, it's a file like this (continuing your *firefox* example):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox
Exec=firefox
Terminal=false
```

Replace `Exec=...` with your command (including arguments too), and `Name=...` with whatever you want. If you want, you can also specify an icon with `Icon=/path/to/icon/file.png`. If your program needs to run as root, you might prefix your command with [`pkexec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html).

Once you are done, you can place this file in `~/.local/share/applications/` and you will find your application in the Gnome Shell.

Read more:

- [Step-by-step tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-desktop-file-linux/)
- [Gnome Documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)
- [Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)

Comment: How does this prevent a user from opening a terminal window and then issue `firefox`? I gather that's what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @PerlDuck: well, I don't know :) My answer is here in the hope it's useful, it's up to the OP to say if it solves their problem or not.